# using select id in .html for javascript

Tags: javascript, html, select

Good day, This is how the code works:

Drop drown select/option(tan) populates the second option(yep, nope,action) assigned .When the

- second option(yep) is selected no assigned function.
- second option(nope) is selected

***PROBLEM***: I want to use the select `id ="m"` inside the `.html` but it is not recognized and it doesn't show the `alert("tada!!")`;

- second option(action) is selected there is an alert message which is 11.

For this line I want to the `<select id='m'>` but it only recognizes the (`#size`).

```
if(val == "tan") {
    $("#size").html("<select id='m'><option value='yep'>yep</option><option value='nope'>nope</option><option value='action'>action</option></select>");
}
```

I set a code for the  but it doesn't work is there a way to use this id inside `$("#size").html`?

```
$("#m").change(function(){
    var val3 = $(this).val();
    if(val3 == "action") {
        alert( 5  + 6 );
    } else if(val3 == "nope") {
        alert("tada!!");
    }
});
```

Please kindly help me. thanks in advance

```
<html>
<head><title>wahaha</title>
<link href="styles.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">
<meta charset="UTF-8">
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-2.2.3.min.js"></script>
<script>

$(document).ready(function(){
    $("#type").on("change",function(){
    // #type Select is selected

    var val = $(this).val();

    if(val == "tan")
    {
       $("#size").html("<select id='m'><option value='yep'>yep</option><option value='nope'>nope</option><option value='action'>action</option></select>");
    }
    else if(val == "-- select one --")
    {
       $("#size").html("<option value='test'>disney</option><option value='test2'>disneyt</option>");
    }
    else if(val == "green")
    {   
    $("#size").html("<option value='test'>olive</option><option value='test2'>mantis green</option><option value='test2'>jungle green</option><option value='test'>asparagus</option>");
    }   
    else if(val == "blue")
    { 
    $("#size").html("<option value='test'>azure</option><option value='test2'>cerulean</option>");
    }
    });

    $("#size").change(function(){
    // #size Select is selected

    var val2 = $(this).val();

    if(val2 == "action")
    {   
        alert( 5  + 6 );
    }
    else if(val2 == "test")
    {
        alert("sample code");
    }
    });

    $("#m").change(function(){
    var val3 = $(this).val();
    if(val3 == "action")
    {   
        alert( 5  + 6 );
    }
    else if(val3 == "nope")
    {
        alert("tada!!");
    }
    });

});
</script>
</head>
<body>
<form>

<select id="type">
        <option value="-- select one --">-- select one -- </option>
        <option value="tan">tan</option>
        <option value="green">green</option>
        <option value="blue">blue</option>

</select>
<select id="size">
    <option value="">-SIZE -- </option>
    <option value="">size </option>
    </select>
<br><br>
</form>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: I dont see anything with an id of "m".  What is that supposed to be?

Comment: Hi,  you can see it after if(val == "tan")

Comment: @SasukeScend please check the answer.

Comment: @SatejS HI THANKYOU SO MUCH! :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here you go, I moved the alert function to the listener that is triggered when the `#size` changes.

> The problem?

The line of code below wasn't replacing the id of the second dropdown with `m`.Only the values inside were changing.

```
$("#size").html("<select id='m'><option value='yep'>yep</option><option value='nope'>nope</option><option value='action'>action</option></select>");
```

**Fixed Code**

```html
<html>
<head><title>wahaha</title>
<link href="styles.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">
<meta charset="UTF-8">
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-2.2.3.min.js"></script>
<script>

$(document).ready(function(){
    $("#type").on("change",function(){
    // #type Select is selected

    var val = $(this).val();

    if(val == "tan")
 {
       $("#size").html("<select id='m'><option value='yep'>yep</option><option value='nope'>nope</option><option value='action'>action</option></select>");
 }
    else if(val == "-- select one --")
 {
       $("#size").html("<option value='test'>disney</option><option value='test2'>disneyt</option>");
    }
 else if(val == "green")
    {   
 $("#size").html("<option value='test'>olive</option><option value='test2'>mantis green</option><option value='test2'>jungle green</option><option value='test'>asparagus</option>");
 } 
 else if(val == "blue")
    { 
 $("#size").html("<option value='test'>azure</option><option value='test2'>cerulean</option>");
    }
 });

    $("#size").change(function(){
    // #size Select is selected

    var val2 = $(this).val();

    if(val2 == "action")
 { 
        alert( 5  + 6 );
    }
 else if(val2 == "test")
    {
  alert("sample code");
 }
 else if(val2 == "nope")
    {
  alert("tada!!");
 }
 });
 
    $("#m").change(function(){
 var val3 = $(this).val();
    if(val3 == "action")
 { 
        alert( 5  + 6 );
    }
 
 });

});
</script>
</head>
<body>
<form>

<select id="type">
        <option value="-- select one --">-- select one -- </option>
        <option value="tan">tan</option>
        <option value="green">green</option>
        <option value="blue">blue</option>

</select>
<select id="size">
    <option value="">-SIZE -- </option>
    <option value="">size </option>
    </select>
<br><br>
</form>
</body>
</html>
```

As a matter of fact, you can actually go ahead and remove the entire function that triggers when `m` changes.

Comment: Hi! Thankyou so much for taking time to answer this problem ^_^